# OpenKeyVal alternative? (open, no-cost, no-login minimal key/value cloud storage)

Tags: javascript, html, networking, key-value, cloud-storage

[OpenKeyVal.org](http://openkeyval.org/) is presently [not working](https://github.com/shinypb/openkeyval/issues/35). Is there a working alternative with no cost, no login and that is as easy to read/write single key/value pairs to in javascript?

Comment: I also like to have ability to update it from command line using `curl`.

Comment: @Vi. Questions asking for tools recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow, I've refunded your bounty and closed this question.

Comment: @bluefeet, [Re-asked](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58966/where-to-store-key-value-pairs-on-the-internet) the question on webapps.SE. Still thinking about how and where to ask it correctly to make it on-topic and useful.